# gitlab: can't push or clone asks for git password after backup restore

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I recently did a backup of my gitlab and restored it on a different machine.
The machine is browsing well, and I can create projects and create teams and all.

But I can't push from local machines to this machine, as its asking for "git password". Now i understand it might have been some identity key issues, so i deleted the old keys of my user from server and added the new ones, but the problem still persists.

I tried checking the ssh error but don't have a clue

```
  ssh -vvvT git@192.168.1.91
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.91 [192.168.1.91] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/brij/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/brij/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/brij/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brij/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brij/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brij/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/brij/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.91" from file "/home/brij/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/brij/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA b0:3d:ef:ee:b4:8a:cb:47:e1:f2:a2:b6:da:ad:29:e5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.91" from file "/home/brij/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/brij/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.1.91' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/brij/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_rsa (0xb7a6c760)
debug2: key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_rsa (0xb7a75188)
debug2: key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/brij/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/brij/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/brij/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@192.168.1.91's password:
```

=======================================================

Update - I found that at the /home/git/.ssh the file authorized_keys is missing while its available at the same location at my other server from where i took the backup
Also there is a symlink between gitlab-shell

gitlab-shell -> /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/

does this have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that at the /home/git/.ssh the file authorized_keys is missing while its available at the same location at my other server from where I took the backup Also there is a symlink between gitlab-shell

gitlab-shell -> /opt/bitnami/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/

I created the symlink and gave a restart to the gitlab server.
Worked like a charm, **but for all my users we'll have to change their keys at the server**, perhaps the folder backup copy and restore is not the right way to move your server, it took me 2 days to resolve this issue.

update - I copied the authorization_keys from older server, and now the users don't have to change their keys also.
but now they would be asked that the server identity is changed, the linux users will have to remove the known_hosts file and let it be regenerated with new known host identity of the server, while it'll work ok for windows users as they'll be asked to replace the identity, and they just need to say "yes" to it.

Comment: Clear known_hosts is the key step in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't mentioned explicitly, I'm not sure if you backup and restore the SSH keys. Generally, you should backup your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (private key) and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (public key) files, otherwise you need to regenerate SSH key and upload to the Gitlab server.

You mentioned:

> i deleted the old keys of my user from server and added the new ones, but the problem still persists.

In detail, it means you should:

- Use `ssh-keygen` to regenerate a key pair (by default it's `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`).
- Upload the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the Gitlab server.

If you think you actually did this, you can double check everything with these instructions:

1. Use `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to regenerate the private key from your public key.
2. Check if the key generate by step 1 is identical to your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` key (email doesn't matter). If they are different, regenerate the key pair and upload to Gitlab server.
3. Check if the public key on Gitlab is identical to key in step 1&2.

Generally, the SSH key should work properly after these checks.

Comment: Hi @miaout17 I did uploaded the keys at server, and even cross checked using ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa and the keys are identical. the public key at gitlab server is identical as well. am just getting crazy on how to fix it